# WordPress Cron Schedule the if and else statement

Tags: cron, wp-cron

I have a custom php loop/function written that works in the following way

```
$start = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+5 hours")));
$end = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_limited_dates_to', true );
$remaining = $end - $start; 
if ($end > $start) {
    wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID, 'not active', 'product_tag', false );
} else {
    wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID, 'active', 'product_tag', false );
}
```

Currently the loop works fine but it is attached with a timer as one can see easily in `$start` and `$end`.
Now what I am trying to get here is something of a product expiry thing going on. I need the cron to work this if & else loop and automatically set the active or not active tags.

How can this be achieved?
Currently I have to manually refresh the page so that the loop runs.

Comment: Where is this code? What triggers it right now?

Comment: I have this code in the custom post type template. I am using WooCommerce. It is the single-product.php file

[link]http://pastebin.ca/2395360[/link]

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: I don't see that code in the pastebin. What line numbers is it on? Also, you've hacked WooCommerce?

Comment: Yes woocommerce has been hacked
[link](http://pastebin.ca/2395360)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`wp_cron`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron) is a PHP level system and so also only runs on page load. It *does not* run on clock time so you'd still need to reload the page to get the loop to run.

Second, to get this working with `wp_cron` you'd need to pull all of your posts with `_limited_dates_to` set and loop through them. You'd need to do that every time the `wp_cron` job runs. That is likely to be a lot of server load as I doubt your expiration times fall into neat blocks that allow you to run a `wp_cron` job every few hours.

As is, you can check one post at a time as needed. That, I would argue, is the better way of doing this than using `wp_cron`.

Even if you have server access that allows you to set up a real system `cron` job you still have the same problem with needing to Loop through all posts with `_limited_dates_to` set.

Unless you have a very convincing reason that this needs to use `wp_cron` or `cron`, and it works as is, I'd say "leave it alone". I don't see the benefits and I do see potential drawbacks.

Comment: I would agree.... and specially running such a thing on a VPS would create a lot of havoc.